# Traveling from South Africa Cape town with Turkish airlines to Miami via Istanbul ,do I need a transit visa?

Tags: visas

Traveling from South Africa Cape town with Turkish airlines to Miami via Istanbul ,do I need a transit visa ?

Comment: how can we know, tell us what passport do you have?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't exit the airport, you won't need to immigrate into Turkey and hence won't need a visa.

Make sure your connecting flight is at the same airport, as Istanbul has two international airports.

Source: own experience, plus [here](https://www.trippy.com/vt/Turkey-3038-2-3019896/Connecting-at-Istanbul-Airport-Require-Visa.html) and [here](https://www.turkishairlines.com/en-bh/istanbul-airport/faq/)